# What are the equipments that are able to meet RNP specifications?

Tags: rnav, rnp, performance-based-navigation

In recent times onboard the aircraft, what are the equipments that are able to meet RNP specifications?.
Many articles that i have read says at present only GNSS (IFR Certified GPS with RAIM or WAAS) is capable of integrity monitoring and alerting (RNP Specification)

Why it is not possible to implement Integrity monitoring and alerting for other RNAV equipment such as IRU/IRU, DME/DME, IRU/DME/DME, IRU/VOR/DME ?.